# Undefined Controller AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My template is loading but I get an error that the controller is undefined. The controller does exist in my sources exactly at the location defined. What is wrong with this code?

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/ng/areq?p0=ItemsController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js:6:450
    at xb
```

This is my html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <ul ng-controller="ItemsController" class="nav">
    <input type="text" value="ItemName" ng-model="newItemName" placeholder="name of new item...">
    <button ng-click="addItem()">Add Me</button>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items.data" id="item{{item.id}}">
      <a href="#">{{item.title}}</a> 
      <a ng-click="deleteItem($index)" class="fa fa-trash-o"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/te.js"></script>
```

---

```
'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.factory("items ", function() {
  var items = {};
  items.data = [];
  return items;
});
myApp.controller("ItemsController", function ItemsController($scope, items) {
  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.deleteItem = function(index) {
    items.data.splice(index, 1);
  }
  $scope.addItem = function(index) {
    items.data.push({
      id: $scope.items.data.length + 1,
      title: $scope.newItemName
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You have a link to edit the question. You should put the code in the description of the question instead of in a comment.

Comment: Is js/te.js the only javascript file you have? I'm guessing you are creating myApp in multiple places.

Comment: yes,it is the only one.

Comment: What does your filestructure look like? Is `js/te.js` reachable from from your html file?

Answer (score 1):

The Only Problem I see in your code is in following line:

```
myApp.factory("items ", function() {
```

**space** in the factory name **"items "** and you are injecting in your controller as items.

Here is the working [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kj4TlClaUosdHLXCoHEm?p=preview) of your code, proof its working fine.

Happy Helping!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem many a times and usually this is caused when you have not included your js in the template.

If its not the case, then if you could share your some part of code, then only anybody will be able to answer it properly.

Comment: i include the js file in the temlate

Comment: You should provide an answer, not assumptions.